# Mounting config maps as volumes in pods, but the mounts are empty

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to mount a ConfigMap as a directory with files in a Pod. The directory is showing up, but there are no files in it. Here's a spec.yaml I'm applying with `kubectl apply -f spec.yaml` :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-map-1
data:
  key-1: Wow I am such a config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: file-printer
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: config-map-1
  containers:
    - name: file-printer
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /config-map-file
      command: ["ls",  "/", "/config-map-file"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

I am running `ls / /config-map-file` so I can see that the directory is being created, but it is not populated:

```
bash-3.2$ kubectl logs file-printer
/:
bin
config-map-file
dev
[...snip...]
usr
var

/config-map-file:
bash-3.2$
```

I would expect `/config-map-file` to have a file in it called `key-1`, but it's empty :(

Here's the output of `kubectl describe pod file-printer` :

```
bash-3.2$ kubectl describe pod file-printer
Name:       file-printer
Namespace:  default
Node:       127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1
Start Time: Mon, 04 Apr 2016 20:28:33 -0500
Labels:     <none>
Status:     Succeeded
IP:     172.17.0.2
Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  file-printer:
    Container ID:   docker://5d08d31a8b06665ce50ba1147df8473a5997406813edff1fa2126cb48464a979
    Image:      gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:e7d168d7db455c45f4d0315d89dbd18806df4784f803c3cc99f8a2e250585b5b
    Port:       
    Command:
      ls
      /
      /config-map-file
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:      BestEffort
      memory:       BestEffort
    State:      Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 04 Apr 2016 20:28:36 -0500
      Finished:     Mon, 04 Apr 2016 20:28:36 -0500
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment Variables:
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Ready     False 
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:   ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:   config-map-1
  default-token-e5g2d:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-e5g2d
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------      -------
  3s        3s      1   {default-scheduler }            Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned file-printer to 127.0.0.1
  2s        2s      1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}         Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with RunContainerError: "addNDotsOption: ResolvConfPath \"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/9472967c2cb9f471067e87560f061647afb9b353c6548f3b64cc06c034e5fe1f/resolv.conf\" does not exist"

  1s    1s  1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1} spec.containers{file-printer}   Normal  Pulling     pulling image "gcr.io/google_containers/busybox"
  0s    0s  1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1} spec.containers{file-printer}   Normal  Pulled      Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/google_containers/busybox"
  0s    0s  1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1} spec.containers{file-printer}   Normal  Created     Created container with docker id 5d08d31a8b06
  0s    0s  1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1} spec.containers{file-printer}   Normal  Started     Started container with docker id 5d08d31a8b06
  0s    0s  1   {kubelet 127.0.0.1}                 Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "file-printer" with RunContainerError: "failed to apply oom-score-adj to container \"exceeded maxTries, some processes might not have desired OOM score\"- /k8s_file-printer.903c39c6_file-printer_default_b64f103c-facd-11e5-b027-7eac684371ee_aa7b4c91"
```

What am I missing? Client & Server are both running 1.2.0.

Comment: Ah, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187624/kubernetes-configmap-volume-doesnt-create-file-in-container

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, could you past the output of `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`?

Comment: @Yu-JuHong Added, thanks!

Comment: Also, I just tried the same spec.yaml on GKE with three nodes, and it worked as expected, so I guess my setup is off somehow. I've just followed the directions at http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/

Comment: Can you add a `sleep` after the `ls` command in the container manifest? This  may help eliminate some noise due to container restarts.

Comment: @Yu-JuHong Sorry, do you mean add a `sleep` so that the events include running time? I'm not sure what noise you mean, or how to add two commands to the container manifest. Sorry to be so ignorant about this stuff!

Comment: The "failed to apply oom-score-adj" failure happened because kubelet was trying to apply the oom score *after* your container started, but the container already exited at that time (since all it did was `ls`). I think that's a false alarm, hence suggesting you to let the container run longer. E.g., `/bin/sh -c 'ls <path_of_config_map>; sleep 600'`. Alternatively, you can just run the sleep command, and `kubectl exec` or `docker exec` into the container to check the volumes.

Comment: Riley, are you running the kubelet in a container?  Which OS are you using?  Is SELinux enabled and enforcing?

Comment: @PaulMorie Yes, I'm running everything in a virtualbox container hosted on OSX- whatever the default os for `docker-machine` is. I'm not sure about SELinux, unfortunately - I don't know much about it. Sorry!

Comment: @RileyLark k, I'm pretty sure docker machine uses Ubuntu, and that SELinux won't be a factor.  However, I wonder: within your vbox VM, is the kubelet running in a container?

Comment: @PaulMorie yes, I have followed the instructions at http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/ exactly

Comment: @RileyLark, what docker version are you using?

Comment: @RileyLark the output of `findmnt` in your VM will also be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes ConfigMap volume doesn't create file in container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187624/kubernetes-configmap-volume-doesnt-create-file-in-container)