# can't mount configMap on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Following the instructions on the [config maps docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/) I can't get the contents of a config map. I create the config

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  special.how: very
  special.type: charm`

And the pod

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      command: [ "busybox", "cat", "/etc/config/special.how" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never`

When I run this pod I get the following

`kubectl logs dapi-test-pod
cat: can't open '/etc/config/special.how': No such file or directory`

If I change the configMap name to be something that doesn't exist, the pod never launches so basically it seems to have found the config map, the volume seems to have been mounted but there is nothing in it.

Following the guide to use env vars from a configMap works correctly, it only seems to be configMap as a file that has the problem. I'm completely stuck :(

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.3+882d296", GitCommit:"882d296a99218da8f6b2a340eb0e81c69e66ecc7", GitTreeState:"not a git tree"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0+$Format:%h$", GitCommit:"$Format:%H$", GitTreeState:"not a git tree"}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes ConfigMap volume doesn't create file in container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187624/kubernetes-configmap-volume-doesnt-create-file-in-container)

Comment: Does the issue linked in that post apply to you? If so, can you try that fix?

Comment: It seems to be the same issue however I'm currently using localkube and am trying to get it implemented on there. I'm having building localkube at the moment though https://github.com/redspread/localkube/issues/60 so I'm stuck for now. I also don't know how to change the mount flag with docker-machine?

Comment: Ok. I guess the answer is to fix this in localkube and it looks like you are on it already.

Comment: I still have the question of how do I set `MountFlags=shared` in docker-machine?

Comment: I would still like to know how to do this with docker-machine however my own situation has been worked around by using https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube instead of localkube. Similar projects and localkube is going to be contributed to minikube anyway.